# System.Timer seems to stop Elapsed event after 2 days or so

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, parallel-processing

I have a very simple console app with the entirety of the high level code shown below:

```
 class Program
{
    static Timer timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();

        Timer_Elapsed(null, null);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        var syncSftp = new Tasks.WindowsServiceTasks.SFTPSync();
        Common.Logging.Logger = new Common.Logging.TextFileAndConsoleLogger();

        syncSftp.Execute();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

There seems to be a strange occurrence where after about 2 days the timer seems to stop triggering the `Elapsed` event.

The quick rundown on this app: It monitors sever folders and sends files out via SFTP. It also goes out and grabs files via SFTP and stores them on local folders. I have logging on every server connection, file move, copy, etc.

It seems that after 2 days the console app stops showing any logging at all. This is what leads me to think the `Elapsed` event stops firing. Not only that but we stop getting files from inbound SFTP and stop sending outbounds. There are no errors whatsoever. The only thing I can think of here is that somehow the console app may be trying to move or copy a file that is open somewhere else.

### What would cause a Timer.Elapsed event to stop firing in simple IO processes?

*I'm thinking maybe there is a catch ya here somewhere such as the program running out of memory or something; however, I do not store any incremented variables such as lists or anything of the sort.*

**In order to avoid polluting the post with extra code that may not be needed I have added the SFTPSync class to a paste bin here:** http://pastebin.com/VfWbPpWt

Comment: How do launch your application ? From a command window, a shortcut or a service ? How do you know you don't have any error. At first glance, I would add a try/catch between the lines `timer.Stop()` and `timer.Start()`.

Comment: It's something we are using as a quick fix so I literally copy the bin folder from VS, transfer it to our server and double click the .exe. Try and catch seems like a good plan; I just hate to have to wait 2 days in between debug sessions. I'm assuming there is no error because the app doesn't close out/crash. Also, if it's caught in the logger it would output to the console

Comment: Windows task scheduler would be a better (and more reliable) option than a `Timer` in a console app. If you want an answer that uses Task Scheduler, I can give you one.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is a pretty horrible class.  One massive crime it commits is swallow any exception raised in the Elapsed event handler without a peep.  Not using try/catch in your event handler is guaranteed to go wrong sooner or later.  When that happens your timer.Start() call will be bypassed and the timer stops ticking.  And you don't know why, there is no peep.  Always favor System.Threading.Timer so your program crashes reliably.